Error resolving 'Properties' in Flutter, this seems to not let me build the apk for the app
I am running into this issue while trying to build apk in flutter.
Terminal output when running flutter build apk:

Also getting this error, I have found other solutions to this but they seem to be for an older version.

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply true
}

include ":app"

Android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Thanks for the help!

The problem is in your settings.gradle. When register plugin in plugins block, org.jetbrains.kotlin.android should not be applied. Change to apply false and you will be alright.
Applying plugins should be done inside app/build.gradle
